# IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition plugins you cannot live without

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea

What are the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition plugins that you use most?

For Java development, I personally use:

- [SonarQube Community Plugin](https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin)
- [JRebel Plugin](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/)
- [Maven Helper](https://github.com/krasa/MavenHelper)
- [Eclipse Code Formatter](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=6546)
- [Apache Equals HashCode and ToString generator](https://github.com/renjith4/ApacheEqualsHashCodeToString)
- [gen-javadoc](http://github.com/bpark/gen-javadoc)

Comment: I think this will be closed rather fast as opinion based.

Comment: There are similar questions that have been voted up. I do see it as a helpful question. Maybe even part of the community wiki.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826/do-you-have-any-recommended-plugins-for-eclipse

Answer (score 3):

These are my favourites:

- [String Manipulation](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162?pr=idea)
- [Grep Console](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125?pr=idea) - to se an error in the console on the first sight, or highlight something
- [Frame Switcher](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7138?pr=idea) - if you use a lot of projects
- [Maven Helper](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179)
- [Eclipse Code Formatter](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=6546)
- [PlantUML integration](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017?pr=idea)
- [BrowseWordAtCaret](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/201?pr=idea)
- [LivePlugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7282?pr=idea) - write scripts for complex text manipulation and actions of all kinds
- [Scratch](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4428?pr=idea) - I still like it more than the bundled functionality